# unresolved external symbol "public static struct"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, struct

In my.h file i have this declaration:

```
/**
*  XMLReader Class
*
*  Defines the required function to parse and get data from XML File
**/
class XMLReader {
public:


    XMLReader();
    ~XMLReader();

    static BOOL  XmlFinder(WCHAR* argv, const WCHAR* log,const WCHAR* Pass);
    /**
    *  Get the data from the XML Files
    *
    *  Returns Boolean if find it
    */

static  struct data
    {
        WCHAR NumProcess[100];
        WCHAR Log[100];
        WCHAR Pass[100];
        WCHAR Mail[100];
        WCHAR memLimit[100];
        WCHAR CPULimit[100];

    }data;


};
```

And in my .cpp file i have defined and inizialized data struct:

```
int  wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{

    struct XMLReader::data;

    wmemcpy(XMLReader::data.Log, L"mama", 50);
    wmemcpy(XMLReader::data.Pass, L"am0r3", 50);
    wmemcpy(XMLReader::data.CPULimit, L"am0r3", 50);
    wmemcpy(XMLReader::data.Mail, L"am0r3", 50);
    wmemcpy(XMLReader::data.NumProcess, L"am0r3", 50);
    wmemcpy(XMLReader::data.memLimit, L"am0r3", 50);
```

But i still have on VS2013 error LNK2001 : Error    3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct XMLReader::data XMLReader::data" (?data@XMLReader@@2U01@A) C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\xmlLiteExample\C++\XmlLiteReader.obj    xmllitereaderTask
and

Error   4   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\xmlLiteExample\C++\Debug\xmllitereaderTask.exe  xmllitereaderTask

Suggestions?

Comment: Well it looks like 'public' and 'static' are both spelled incorrectly somewhere in your code.

Comment: Where? maybe in title

Comment: @kenhero _unresolved external symbol "**punlic**: **stati** struct XMLReader::data on .obj_

Comment: thank you but this is not code,it's Error List

Answer (score 1):

> And in my .cpp file i have defined and inizialized data struct

You have not.

```
struct XMLReader::data;
```

This is a redeclaration of the *type* `struct XMLReader::data;`, not a definition of the static class member. Such redeclaration has no effect.

`XMLReader::data` (no `struct`) is the *name* of the static data member. You need to define it with both the type and the name, and **you cannot define in a function, you have to do it at the file level**:

```
struct XMLReader::data XMLReader::data;
```

It is not recommended to use `data` as a name for both a variable and a struct tag. In fact it is not recommended to use `data` as a name for anything. It doesn't provide any information. And of course don't use anything as a name for both a struct tag and a variable. This is confusing and is only allowed for compatibility with an obscure C feature. If you change these things to different things you can do something like this:

```
XMLReader::options_t XMLReader::options = { 
       L"mama", 
       L"am0r3", 
       L"am0r3", 
       L"am0r3", 
       L"am0r3"
       L"am0r3"
};
```

which is preferred over your attempt to dynamically initialize the members, if only yours invoke undefined behaviour (you cannot copy 50 characters from a string literal that only has 5).

Last but not least, don't use character arrays. Use `std::string`. If you must use (not-quite-standards-compliant in Visual Studio) wide characters, use `std::wstring`.